# password_verify function in php is not working despite proper varchar length

Tags: php, password-hash

I am learning php and was trying this php function but for some reason it isn't working despite trying all the answers here.
I hashed 'b' using password_hash function and tried to verify it. Here is my code

```
if(password_verify('b', 
'$2y$10$OCZvoaVXX00xBkwpfGfgOu9AGXutvcZkhvpqSVWpL6v.BNnLsAN4u')){
echo "valid";
}else{
echo "invalid";
}
```

Comment: Please show us all the code (including the hashing). Without knowing how you got that hash, we won't be able to evaluate what actually happens.

Comment: Your code works with a freshly generated password hash. What salt did you use to generate your hash?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/kMaIL working as expected

Comment: yes you guys are right. It was actually the hash that was the problem that day. It turned out I was hashing an empty string.

Answer (score 5):

That's a hash of an empty string:

```
$hash = '$2y$10$OCZvoaVXX00xBkwpfGfgOu9AGXutvcZkhvpqSVWpL6v.BNnLsAN4u';
var_dump(password_verify('', $hash));
```

> bool(true)

Find out where you're getting the input and work back from there, because it definitely isn't **b**.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I accidentally ended up hashing empty string that day. I realized that much later. Again thanks for your time.